# List to Byte conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte

I have a conversion error, following is the code.

```
var result = ent1.EncryptPasswords.FromSqlRaw(
  "EXEC [dbo].[sp_EncryptPasswordforEmployee] @password={0}", 
   param1
).ToList();

var emp1 = ent1.Employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == vModel.UserInfo.Email 
   && (a.CustomerId != vModel.CustInfo.CustomerCode));

if (emp1 != null)
{
    emp1.Password = result;   //This line shows error 
}
```

Password is byte.
Result is list

I am getting error as "Cannot implicitly convert system.collection.generic.list<> to byte".

Comment: It seems unbelievable that you'd want the Password to be just a Byte.  Maybe a Byte Array?  Also what type of List is Result?

Comment: Yes,I want byte[].
 Result is' list<encryptPassword>' it is a DBset

Comment: "Result is list" - can you clarify? List of what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to assign the entire stored procedure result to the **Password** property.

You would have to grab the first occurrence in the result list, get the password field value and only then assign it, like so:

```
    emp1.Password = result[0].Password
```

Considering, of course, that you only want the first occurrence and that the result occurrence object contains the Password property.

I hope this helped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).